# Apply icon pack in an Android Emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, icons

I'm trying to develop an Android icon pack but I haven't a device to test it yet, is there a way to apply it to an emulator running through Eclipse?

Comment: How would you try it with real device? Try the same approach with emulator

Answer (score 0):

You may use "bluestack". Install suitable launcher in bluestack and apply your icon pack in regular way.
Personally I also use this to test my icon pack.